# android httpclient.execute exception working on 4.1.2 but on 2.3.3 doesn't

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, httpclient

It's work on samsung s2(android 4.1.2) but on motorola mb526(android 2.3.3) doesn't working.
Help.

```
public class JSONParser extends AsyncTask {
....
getResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);  // ERRORS!
...
```

the exceptions:

```
10-02 15:55:08.882: W/System.err(11156): java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out
10-02 15:55:08.882: W/System.err(11156):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.read(Native Method)
10-02 15:55:08.889: W/System.err(11156): java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out
10-02 15:55:08.889: W/System.err(11156):    at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.read(BlockGuard.java:273)
10-02 15:55:08.889: W/System.err(11156):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:458)
10-02 15:55:08.889: W/System.err(11156):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:85)
10-02 15:55:08.889: W/System.err(11156):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
10-02 15:55:08.889: W/System.err(11156):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:191)
10-02 15:55:08.889: W/System.err(11156):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:82)
10-02 15:55:08.897: W/System.err(11156):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.read(Native Method)
10-02 15:55:08.905: W/System.err(11156):    at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.read(BlockGuard.java:273)
10-02 15:55:08.905: W/System.err(11156):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:458)
10-02 15:55:08.905: W/System.err(11156):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:85)
10-02 15:55:08.905: W/System.err(11156):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
10-02 15:55:08.905: W/System.err(11156):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:191)
10-02 15:55:08.905: W/System.err(11156):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:82)
10-02 15:55:08.905: W/System.err(11156):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
10-02 15:55:08.913: W/System.err(11156):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
10-02 15:55:08.913: W/System.err(11156):    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:179)
10-02 15:55:08.913: W/System.err(11156):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
10-02 15:55:08.913: W/System.err(11156):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
10-02 15:55:08.913: W/System.err(11156):    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
10-02 15:55:08.913: W/System.err(11156):    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
10-02 15:55:08.913: W/System.err(11156):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:425)
10-02 15:55:08.913: W/System.err(11156):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
10-02 15:55:08.921: W/System.err(11156):    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:179)
10-02 15:55:08.921: W/System.err(11156):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
10-02 15:55:08.921: W/System.err(11156):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
10-02 15:55:08.921: W/System.err(11156):    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
10-02 15:55:08.921: W/System.err(11156):    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
10-02 15:55:08.921: W/System.err(11156):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:425)
10-02 15:55:08.921: W/System.err(11156):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
10-02 15:55:08.928: W/System.err(11156):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
10-02 15:55:08.928: W/System.err(11156):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
10-02 15:55:08.928: W/System.err(11156):    at com.androidhive.pushnotifications.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:65)
10-02 15:55:08.928: W/System.err(11156):    at com.androidhive.pushnotifications.JSONParser.doInBackground(JSONParser.java:111)
10-02 15:55:08.928: W/System.err(11156):    at com.androidhive.pushnotifications.JSONParser.doInBackground(JSONParser.java:1)
10-02 15:55:08.928: W/System.err(11156):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
10-02 15:55:08.928: W/System.err(11156):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
10-02 15:55:08.928: W/System.err(11156):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
10-02 15:55:08.928: W/System.err(11156):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
10-02 15:55:08.936: W/System.err(11156):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
10-02 15:55:08.936: W/System.err(11156):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
10-02 15:55:08.936: W/System.err(11156):    at com.androidhive.pushnotifications.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:65)
10-02 15:55:08.936: W/System.err(11156):    at com.androidhive.pushnotifications.JSONParser.doInBackground(JSONParser.java:111)
10-02 15:55:08.936: W/System.err(11156):    at com.androidhive.pushnotifications.JSONParser.doInBackground(JSONParser.java:1)
10-02 15:55:08.936: W/System.err(11156):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
10-02 15:55:08.936: W/System.err(11156):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
10-02 15:55:08.936: W/System.err(11156):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
10-02 15:55:08.944: W/System.err(11156):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
10-02 15:55:08.952: W/System.err(11156):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
10-02 15:55:08.952: W/System.err(11156):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
10-02 15:55:08.952: W/System.err(11156):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
10-02 15:55:08.952: W/System.err(11156):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Comment: does your motorola have actually access to your server?

Comment: yes from the web browser i can access the link

Comment: weird. Exact same apk on both? The execute part in in the doInBackground? (it really seems to be, but you never know)

Comment: yes debug app from eclipse